# Online Latin Synonyms and Other Crossword Resources

Tags: classical-latin, resource-request

Are there any online searchable synonym lists, i.e. thesauri?
I don't mean scanned versions of books, I mean apps or search
engines that list synonyms given a specific search word.

I am interested in doing the O Tempora! crossword and having a decent synonym resource seems to be the first step.

Thank you
David.

Comment: There is a well known Thesaurus of Epithets and Synonyms called 'Gradus ad Parnassum.' Wikipedia will explain. Here's the address of a more recent lookalike:  https://adsa.cs.illinois.edu/mlosd/14-prof-luisa-kertzmann-v-1/9781241168056-gradus-ad-parnassum-on-a-plan-nearly-resembling-.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This wonderful [site](https://nikita-moor.github.io/dictionaries/), contains digitized version of regular dictionaries and synonym dictionary. It does not work online though, and you are required to download a viewer for the dictionaries. But if I understand correctly, it answers your requirements as it is searchable and will display the words nicely. see [screenshot](https://nikita-moor.github.io/dictionaries/dictionaries/Dumesnil1819.html) for one of those synonym dictionaries.